# Dynamic database requests without query string parameters

Tags: apostrophe-cms

So I have a list of project cards (projects are pieces), and I would like to be able to have an overlay populate with content from whichever card is clicked.

I was thinking of having each project card have a `data-slug` attribute that could then be used in a cursor lookup in the page's javascript: `return self.apos.docs.getManager('project').find(req, {slug: selected})`
, which would then use `$('#overlay').innerHTML()` to update the content, but it feels like there must be a better way to do this. I'm pretty sure at this point that I've been trying to use front-end code to access back-end apostrophe functions, which won't work.

What I have currently:

```
$(function () {
  var projects = document.querySelectorAll('.project');
  console.log(projects);
  $(projects).on('click', function () {
    var slug = this.id;
    var project = self.apos.docs.getManager('standard-project').find(req, { slug: slug });
  });
```

The line where I define project just creates all kinds of errors.

I guess another option would be to render and hide an overlay for each project unless it has an `active` class, but that seems terribly inefficient and would probably increase page load time  by several seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stoked you're checking out Apostrophe!

The internal team has solved this a few ways.

The simplest would be to AJAX the markup from the actual piece show page template into your overlay. This would consist of leaving some clue in front-end of your card (like the url to the page) and then picking that up in a click handler, requesting the page, and populating the markup with what was received.

The received markup would be that in your `apostrophe-pieces-pages` module's `views/show.html`

Comment: I have jQuery loading the results of `showPage()` alright, but I'm running into issues in that it seems like video widgets never get their `play()` method called, so oembed never populates the widget. I'm assuming I would have to call the `play()` method in the callback for `jQuery.load(...)`, but passing in the arguments is stumping me and looking through the source hasn't gotten me anywhere unfortunately.